# Troubleshooting blocking requests in node.js

Tags: node.js

Are there any tools in node.js that could provide list of all the pending async calls? This would be particularly helpful in the case if an async call is waiting for the response and because of which the request is stuck.

Also Is there any tool which could give stack trace of the single thread in node.js?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't give you a list of pending I/O, but [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) does allow you to use the same JS debugger as Chrome's Developer Tools, which allows you to set breakpoints and inspect the stack.